# Ajax inside Datatables Custom Button Action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I want to store datatables data inside an array or json format and use it to pass to php for **FPDF** use. In my datatable I created a custom button named "PDF", when the button is click I want to store the data and pass it into php via post. I have this code, but it wont work if I put ajax inside the action function of the custom button I made. It doesnt go to the url I declared. Here's the code:

**EDITED**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#stud_list').DataTable({
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 1,
                className: 'noVis'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'PDF',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    },
                    action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
                       $.ajax({
                            url: 'pdfViewStudent.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: table.row().data().toArray(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(returnedData) {
                                console.log(returnedData);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                'colvis'
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: -1,
                visible: false
            }],
            initComplete: function() {
                this.api().columns([4, 5, 6]).every(function() {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function() {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I edited the code, the error was gone but nothing happens also.

**ADDED HTML CODE:**

```
<table id="stud_list" class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Initials</th>
                                        <th>Grade</th>
                                        <th>Section</th>
                                        <th>Gender</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php 
                                        $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tbl_student") or die(mysqli_error());

                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                        ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['Initials']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['gradeLevel_id']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['section_id']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['gender']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="studentProfile.php?studId=<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i></a>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editStudent" data-studaydi="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>" data-cardaydi="<?php echo $row['card_id']; ?>" data-seksyon="<?php echo $row['section_id']; ?>" data-gardyan="<?php echo $row['Parents_No']; ?>" data-location="<?php echo $row['address']; ?>" data-ln="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>" data-fn="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>" data-mn="<?php echo $row['Initials']; ?>" data-gn="<?php echo $row['gender']; ?>" data-cy="<?php echo $row['cyear']; ?>" data-gr="<?php echo $row['gradeLevel_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i></button>
                                            <a onclick="javascript: return confirm('DO YOU REALLY WANT TO DELETE THIS STUDENT?');" href="removeStudent.php?id=<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-remove fa-1x"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
```

Comment: Well , i am pretty sure that your datatable it is not in the correct format.Can you please add html code here?

Comment: At the very least, the first line of the dataTable definition should be `var table = $('#stud_list').DataTable({`

Comment: I think there's no problem with the html code. Whenever I define the table, it gives me an error that it cannot read the property "row" of undefined.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Tried it, no error but nothing happens. It doesn't direct me to the URL. And nothing also in the console.

Comment: Where are you trying to add the button? Can you just past the html code please?

Comment: There are probably further mistakes in the dataTable definition. As @MrAlb suggests, post your HTML so he can check the dataTable definition against it.

Comment: @Khrisdaniels you are trying to add a button on each row or in the header of the table?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I added the HTML code of the table.

Comment: @MrAlb I added the HTML code of the Table. Not a button in each row. I am using the Datatables [Custom Button](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html) to add a button to make a pdf file of the table. Just like Datatable HTML 5 Export Buttons.

Comment: @MrAlb I want to pass the array or json to the PHP script whenever I click the Custom Button I made so I can use it for creating pdf using FPDF.

Comment: @Khrisdaniels In the  javascript code smth is missing.I mean the brackets of $(document).ready(function() {...
 var table = $('#stud_list').DataTable({  ... are not closed, so see carefully again.

Comment: @MrAlb I'm sorry about that, I forgot to put the whole script. There's no missing code. It's just that nothing happens whenever I click the button.